# Unwanted default thick axis lines in R plot function

Tags: r, plot, axes

When I make any plot in R it always results with a thicker axis line along the numbered portion of the surrounding box. It's a nuisance as I must always turn the axes off in plot(), and then redraw them with zero thickness. I've noticed other labmates' computers don't seem to have this problem which makes me wonder where the problem is coming from.

Plot 1 generates my unwanted thick axes lines, Plot 2 works as a solution:

```
x<-c(1:10)
y<-c(1:10)
# Plot 1
plot(x,y, main="Plot 1")
# Plot 2
plot(x, y, xaxt='n', yaxt='n', main="Plot 2")
axis(1, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
axis(2, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
```

I'm running RStudio 0.98.501 on Mac OSX 10.9.4

Any ideas on root of the error much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should be able to add those images now.

Comment: On some systems (maybe due to antialiasing settings, etc.) parts of the axes appear thicker because the lines of the box and axes are plotted over one another (do `plot(x, y, bty='n')` to see that the axes only extend to the outer ticks). When I have this problem, I usually just do a `box()` (or e.g. `box(lwd=2)`) after all other plotting commands, and this tends to make it less noticeable.

Comment: @jbaums Yes indeed you are correct that they're plotting over one another. The redrawing box trick works to cover things up - though making figures to publication requirements (i.e. line thickness) it does still add the extra steps... though minor when compared to all the other things. Really just a visual default nuisance I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: If you're willing to dive into `ggplot2`, this discussion has some likely leads:  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/ggplot2-Controlling-line-width-of-panel-borders-td3075489.html

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new plot function, something along the lines of this should work:

```
plot = function(x, y, ...){
    plot(x, y, xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
    axis(1, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
    axis(2, lwd=0, lwd.ticks=1)
}
```